# Slow UpdatePanel in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, performance

I was trying to figure out why my UpdatePanel is so SLOW (after Button1's postback) in an ASP.NET application:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this is slow!!
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            btn.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssfff");
        }
    }
}
```

I was searching here in StackOverflow but I couldn't find a straight forward answer.
Anyone knows something that might speed this up?

I've seen a faster UpdatePanel button postback when I run my webapplication using http://Junior-PC. But when I use http://localhost is pretty slower.

The only difference between a regular web application and this one is in Web application properties-> *Web* tab-> *Servers* section where is marked *Use Local IIS Web Server*-> *Project Url*: http://localhost/ and *Override application root URL*.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you mean by "so SLOW"?

Comment: there a number of things that can affect response time, best thing to suggest is to try without the asp:UpdatePanel and compare if that is what you thing causes the slowness

Comment: @asawyer after asp.net button postback. @Ivanov the time seems to be the same with or without UpdatePanel.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Toolkit script manager and not ASP.NET ScriptManager ?

Comment: @Madhur I also tried with ASP.NET ScriptManager, just to see if there is a difference. Nothing has changed :-(

Comment: @Junior Use HttpWatch or Fiddler to profile the requests and see what is taking time ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, don't forget do disable IPv6 in (enter about:config in URL). Except that, code looks fine. What's the speed of regular postbacks? Tried other browsers?

Comment: Hey Hrvoje, I'm using IE. Firefox is also slow when postback is being fired

Comment: Is your page literally what you posted? Maybe your actual page has a boatload of viewstate to download that you can trim?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use classic script manager:

```
asp:ScriptManager
```

instead of:

```
cc1:ToolkitScriptManager.
```

Morover please unregister AjaxControlToolkit because in this case it is unnecessary. Let us know it helps.